# Change folder location for unsaved files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a folder named Notes which I open in VSCode and jot down random stuff I am working on at the time. Sort of like sticky notes. Most of them are just unsaved because it's just a temporary note that I don't really care to save. More and more often I've been organizing stuff that is more important into subfolders, so I decided to commit this folder into a Git repo and have a scheduled task that runs every 30mins which automatically commits and pushes to my GitLab server. The script is something like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "git.exe" -ArgumentList "add ." -NoNewWindow -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath "git.exe" -ArgumentList "commit -a -m `"$((Get-Date).ToString())`"" -NoNewWindow -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath "git.exe" -ArgumentList "push" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

The problem is the unsaved files aren't stored within the workspace but instead are stored in:
%APPDATA%\Code\Backups

Most of the time I don't really care about unsaved files but I tend to get busy and have several unsaved tabs open and when I have some down time I will run through all the tabs and save any that are important. I want to insure these files are backed up. Is there anyway to override the Backup path for a specific workspace so that unsaved files get stored in .vscode of the workspace? This would then allow the unsaved work to get picked up in my git commits.